# function to output image to browsers returns text/html type

Tags: php

I have the below function to output an image to the browser

```
function sendImage(string $file, int $browser_cache = 2592000) {

  if (file_exists($file)) {

    $mime = getimagesize($file)['mime'];

    header("Content-Type: ". $mime);
    header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=".$browser_cache);
    header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$browser_cache).' GMT');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
  }
}
```

call the function

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/image.png';
sendImage($file);
```

The content type output shows text/html and there is no response content. No errors either. The file definitely exists.
I cant quite figure out the error in the function.

Comment: may be you can replace getimagesize function with 'mime_content_type($file['name'])'

Comment: thanks i updated my code. Still trying to make the function work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work as intended.
You think you should add a check (e.g. function returns) to avoid possible warnings, and get a fallback if the file doesn't exists.

```
function sendImage(string $file, int $browser_cache = 2592000) {

    if (!file_exists($file)) return false ;

    $mime = getimagesize($file)['mime'];

    header("Content-Type: ". $mime);
    header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=".$browser_cache);
    header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$browser_cache).' GMT');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Then you could check this :

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/image.png';
if (!sendImage($file)) {
    echo "file not found" ;
}
```

Additionally, if the `$file` is not an image, `getimagesize()` will returns false. And `getimagesize($file)['mime']` will emit a warning.

```
$infos = getimagesize($file) ;
if (!$infos) return false ; // Or something else to specialize the fallback.
$mime = $infos['mime'];
```

Comment: i did as you mentioned. When run from within the script its returns $mime as null. So i'm guessing the problem might be with the parameter. echo $file shows '/var/www/html/images/image.png'. Would this be correct way to input? or should i provide the http://localhost/...

Comment: when i run separate from the main script its returns a file doesn't exist error.

Comment: Yes, `file_exists()`, `getimagesize()` and `readfile()` functions uses the filesystem path, not URL.

Comment: Ok you definitely pointed me in the right direction so i will accept your answer. But one last question i am getting this error output to the browser. Does it make sense to you ---- the image "http://localhost/" cannot be displayed because it contains errors. MIME type is returning correctly.

Comment: Look at the source in your browser. I think you have something written before the image data.