# error using readfile php function

Tags: php

I have this function which outputs an image to the browser. However i get an error image cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

I've done the file_exists check and the image headers are all applied correctly.

```
function sendImage(string $file, int $browser_cache = 2592000) {

  if (file_exists($file)) {

    header("Content-Type: ". mime_content_type($file));
    header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=".$browser_cache);
    header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$browser_cache).' GMT');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));

    readfile($file);
    exit;

  } else {
    echo 'file does not exist';
  }
}
```

Call the function

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/image.png';

sendImage($file);
```

The image opens in my browser just fine. But displays an error with this function.

Comment: didn't you already post this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48367156/function-to-output-image-to-browsers-returns-text-html-type

Comment: Yes i did and i corrected some errors in my script but now its seem to have narrowed down to the readfile function. The earlier question had a problem with the mime type which is now resolved.

Comment: [*"Ok you definitely pointed me in the right direction so i will accept your answer. But one last question i am getting this error output to the browser. Does it make sense to you ---- the image "localhost/"; cannot be displayed because it contains errors. MIME type is returning correctly."*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48367156/function-to-output-image-to-browsers-returns-text-html-type#comment83721737_48367259) - I wouldn't call that resolved.

Comment: sigh! i accepted the answer because i found the source of the problem outside the sendImage function. Now i corrected those errors and my question is specific to Readfile(). It has nothing to do with the earlier question and i'm not going to get my answer there.

Comment: Fair enough; I've reopened.

Answer (score 0):

What I can tell from experience is that `readfile` does not work with large files.

And sometimes, even when you got the PHP part right there are other points of failures.

I suggest using the `X-Sendfile` header instead of manually outputting the file:

```
function sendImage(string $file, int $browser_cache = 2592000) {
  $path = realpath($file);

  if ($path !== false) {
    header("Content-Type: ". mime_content_type($file));
    header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=".$browser_cache);
    header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$browser_cache).' GMT');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));

    header('X-Sendfile: '.$path);
    exit;

  } else {
    echo 'file does not exist';
  }
}
```

Of course you have to enable it in your webserver configuration for it to work.

Comment: I tried both the realpath and x-sendfile header. Didn't work. I don't think its the problem here. I've been using adaptive-images library so far. And it uses the same readfile function without problems. The max image size is 330kb.